# How to disassemble .elf file to .asm file in riscv

Tags: c, gcc, riscv

I have generated a .elf file by using

> riscv64-unknown-elf-gcc -march=rv64imac -mabi=lp64 -Tlinker.ld *.o add.o -o add.elf -static -nostartfiles -lm -lgcc

And now I want to see the stack to check the values assigned to variables used in my add.c. I believe the same can be obtained from a .dasm/.asm file. How can I generate a .asm/.dasm file from an .elf file?

Answer (score 1):

Just as an extension to dratenik's answer.

I am using riscv32-unknown-elf-objdump --disassemble-all NAME.elf > NAME.disasm

This way you don't even have to go over the -S option. And can just disassemble your .elf file.

Again as dratenik noted you need to adjust the prefix of objdump to you toolchain aka. your compiler prefix

Answer (score 0):

You can stop gcc at the assembly stage by adding the `-S` switch, the file output by `-o` will then be an asm source file. Or you can let gcc finish and then take the resulting binary apart with `objdump -d`. Of course you need to run the `objdump` binary from the same toolchain, not your system one.